# How can I import a js file that contains a self calling function onto a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a js file that forms an interesting particle effect when attached to a div. Thing is, I need to import it onto a React application.

The Script works perfectly on codepen. But is there anyway to make it run on React?
I have tried importing the .js file through index.html but to no avail
Here's the codepen link:
`"https://codepen.io/zarrymyles/pen/LYWpaJr"` 
Hope somebody can help me with this.
Thanks in advance! 
Edit 1: Grammar.

Answer (score 0):

just import the module file in your code, e.g:

```
import 'iife.js';
```

NOTE: this will be executed when your module (where you imported it) executed.